# How to make something clicked after a few seconds?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make something, do what it would as if it were clicked, after 5 seconds of the page loading. The ID of the button I'm trying to make clicked is `openSidebar`. Here's what I have but I don't know what to fill the function with.

```
function clickOpenSidebar(){
    setTimeout(function(){

    }, 5000);
}

onload = "clickOpenSidebar();"
```

Comment: @ZachSaucier `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` is typically better because `onclick` only allows one event to be attached. But, `onclick` is fine so long as the programmer knows this.

Comment: @ZachSaucier - Nooo... Don't ever use `onclick` or `onload`. They are like last decade technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can programmatically fire a click on the element using `click()`.

Code:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("openSidebar");
foo.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert('clicked');
}, false);

function clickOpenSidebar() {
    setTimeout(

    function () {
        document.getElementById('openSidebar').click();
    }, 5000);
}

clickOpenSidebar();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nwerb/

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect :) I'll accept after 7 minutes.

Comment: It has a time limit. I have to wait 4 more minutes.